# Jquery RegEx for Date Validation for formats mm/dd/yy, mm/dd/yyyy and

Tags: jquery, regex, validation, date

I am doing a Date validation and need to validate date for different formats. I could not find a Regex that validates a date value for all the following formats mm/dd/yyy, mm/dd/yy, m/d/yyyy
I tried the following which  failed for the mm/dd/yy format.

```
var dtRegex = new RegExp(/\b\d{1,2}[\/-]\d{1,2}[\/-]\d{4}\b/);
var valid = dtRegex.test(dtValue);
```

If not in one Regex could you help me with a regex for each format separately.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Replace `\d{4}` with `(?:\d{2}|\d{4})`.

Comment: A great place to test your regular expressions and fine tune them is Regex101: https://regex101.com/